# Ошибка инициализации MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql

Помогите, пожалуйста, запустить mySql 8.0
Файл my.ini

```
[mysqld]

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES 
datadir=d:/Server/data/DB/data/
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

запускаю из командной строки

```
d:\Server\bin\mysql-8.0\bin\mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=root
```

в результате получаю в каталоге **d:/Server/data/DB/data/** файл *.err с текстом

```
2019-11-08T08:22:42.107119Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2019-11-08T08:22:42.107216Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] d:\Server\bin\mysql-8.0\bin\mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18) initializing of server in progress as process 3964
2019-11-08T08:22:42.128471Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012576] [InnoDB] Unable to create temporary file; errno: 2
2019-11-08T08:22:42.129846Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012929] [InnoDB] InnoDB Database creation was aborted with error Generic error. You may need to delete the ibdata1 file before trying to start up again.
2019-11-08T08:22:42.132372Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2019-11-08T08:22:42.132912Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013455] [Server] The newly created data directory d:\Server\data\DB\data\ by --initialize is unusable. You can remove it.
2019-11-08T08:22:42.133805Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-11-08T08:22:42.134717Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] d:\Server\bin\mysql-8.0\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.18)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: Что непонятно в тексте *Unable to create temporary file; errno: 2*? Error 2 - это  "file cannot be found". Нужно было в каталог, указанный как datadir, скопировать полностью исходный (созданный при инсталляции) datadir.

Comment: То и непонятно какой именно файл он не может создать. Или там написано какой? "Созданный при инсталляции" это когда? с сайта скачал архив mysql-8.0.18-winx64, его содержимое скопировать в d:/Server/data/DB/data/ ?

Comment: Почему - создать? "file cannot be found" переводится как "файл не может быть НАЙДЕН". Что неудивительно - его и правда нет в указанном каталоге. Да, имеется в виду файл `ibtmp1.`.

Comment: Изначально даже папки `d:/Server/data/DB/data/` нет. Она создается по запуску инициализации. Нету в скачаном архиве ни `ibtmp1`, ни `ibdata1`.

Comment: ??? каком таком "скачанном архиве"???

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=490026

Comment: Вы точно выполнили ВСЕ инструкции из https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-install-archive.html, строго в указанном порядке и с точностью до запятых и переносов строк? нигде не выпендрились типа "это очевидно", "и так сойдёт" или "тут при всём желании не накосячишь"?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-initialize-data-directory.html дошел сюда. Отличия были только в пути установки, не в `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0` а в `d:\Server\bin\mysql-8.0\`    Ошибка на пункте https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-initialize-data-directory.html

Comment: Пробовал с помощью инсталятора 8.0.11. Все по дефолту. Ошибка на скрине https://imgshare.io/image/att.x3lgg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ищи другую машину, ставь там mySql, инициализируй, а после, копируй созданные папки себе.